# Training submodel instead of full model Tensorflow Federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to modify TensorFlow Federated example. I want to create a submodel from the original model and use the newly created one for the training phase and then send the weights to the server so that he will update the original model.

I know this shouldn't have been done inside `client_update` but the server should send the correct submodel directly to the client, but for now i prefer doing so.

For now i have 2 problem:

1. Seems like i can't create a new model inside the `client_update` function like so:

```py
    @tf.function
    def client_update(model, dataset, server_message, client_optimizer):
        """Performans client local training of `model` on `dataset`.
        Args:
          model: A `tff.learning.Model`.
          dataset: A 'tf.data.Dataset'.
          server_message: A `BroadcastMessage` from server.
          client_optimizer: A `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`.
        Returns:
          A 'ClientOutput`.
        """
    
        model_weights = model.weights
    
        import dropout_model
        dropout_model = dropout_model.get_dropoutmodel(model)
    
    
        initial_weights = server_message.model_weights
        tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, t: v.assign(t), model_weights,
                              initial_weights)
        .....
```

The error is this one:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

The model created is like this:

```py
    def from_original_to_submodel(only_digits=True):
        """The CNN model used in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629.
        Args:
          only_digits: If True, uses a final layer with 10 outputs, for use with the
            digits only EMNIST dataset. If False, uses 62 outputs for the larger
            dataset.
        Returns:
          An uncompiled `tf.keras.Model`.
        """
        data_format = 'channels_last'
        input_shape = [28, 28, 1]
        max_pool = functools.partial(
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D,
            pool_size=(2, 2),
            padding='same',
            data_format=data_format)
        conv2d = functools.partial(
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D,
            kernel_size=5,
            padding='same',
            data_format=data_format,
            activation=tf.nn.relu)
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            conv2d(filters=32, input_shape=input_shape),
            max_pool(),
            conv2d(filters=64),
            max_pool(),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(410, activation=tf.nn.relu), #20% dropout
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10 if only_digits else 62),
        ])
        return model
    
    def get_dropoutmodel(model):
        keras_model = from_original_to_submodel(only_digits=False)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model, loss=loss, input_spec=model.input_spec)
```

2. Is more like a theorical question. I would like to train a sub model like i said, so i would take the original model weights sent from the server `initial_weights` and for each layer i would assign a sublist of random weights to the submodel weights. For example, `initial_weights` for the layer 6 contains 100 elements, my new submodel for the same layer has only 40 elements, i would choose from a random with a seed the 40 elements, doing the training and then send the seed to the server, so that he would choose the same indeces and then update only them. Is that correct? My second version was to create still 100 elements(40 random and 60 equal to 0) but i think this will mess the model performance when aggregating on the server side.

EDIT:

I have modified the `client_update_fn` function like so:

```
@tff.tf_computation(tf_dataset_type, server_message_type)
def client_update_fn(tf_dataset, server_message):
    model = model_fn()
    submodel = submodel_fn()
    client_optimizer = client_optimizer_fn()
    return client_update(model, submodel, tf_dataset, server_message, client_optimizer)
```

Adding a new parameter to the function `build_federated_averaging_process` like so:

```
def build_federated_averaging_process(
        model_fn, submodel_fn,
        server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
        client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)):
```

And in the `main.py` i did this:

```
def tff_submodel_fn():
    keras_model = create_submodel_dropout(only_digits=False)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model, loss=loss, input_spec=train_data.element_type_structure)

iterative_process = simple_fedavg_tff.build_federated_averaging_process(
    tff_model_fn, tff_submodel_fn, server_optimizer_fn, client_optimizer_fn)
```

Now inside the `client_update` i can use the submodel:

```
@tf.function
def client_update(model, submodel, dataset, server_message, client_optimizer):
    """Performans client local training of `model` on `dataset`.
    Args:
      model: A `tff.learning.Model`.
      dataset: A 'tf.data.Dataset'.
      server_message: A `BroadcastMessage` from server.
      client_optimizer: A `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`.
    Returns:
      A 'ClientOutput`.
    """



    model_weights = model.weights
    initial_weights = server_message.model_weights      
    submodel_weights = submodel.weights
    tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, t: v.assign(t), submodel_weights,
                          initial_weights)
    num_examples = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
    loss_sum = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Explicit use `iter` for dataset is a trick that makes TFF more robust in
    # GPU simulation and slightly more performant in the unconventional usage
    # of large number of small datasets.
    weights_delta = []
    testing = False
    if not testing:
        for batch in iter(dataset):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                outputs = model.forward_pass(batch)
            grads = tape.gradient(outputs.loss, submodel_weights.trainable)
            client_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, submodel_weights.trainable))
            batch_size = tf.shape(batch['x'])[0]
            num_examples += batch_size
            loss_sum += outputs.loss * tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)

        weights_delta = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                              submodel_weights.trainable,
                                              initial_weights.trainable)
    client_weight = tf.cast(num_examples, tf.float32)
    return ClientOutput(weights_delta, client_weight, loss_sum / client_weight)
```

I recieve this error:

```
    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'].

Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f27af18b740 (most recent call first):
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1853 in _create_c_op
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2041 in __init__
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3557 in _create_op_internal
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 599 in _create_op_internal
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 748 in _apply_op_helper
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1276 in delete_iterator
  File "virtual-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 549 in __del__

Process finished with exit code 11
```

For now the model is the same as the original one, i copied the function `create_original_fedavg_cnn_model` inside `create_submodel_dropout` so i don't understand what's wrong

Answer (score 3):

In general, we cannot create variables inside a `tf.function` since the method will be re-used repeatedly in a TFF computation; though technically [variables may only be created once](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function#variables_may_only_be_created_once_2) inside a `tf.function`. We can see that the `model` is actually created *outside* the `tf.function` in most of the TFF library code, and passed in as an argument to a `tf.function` (example: https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/44d012f690005ecf9217e3be970a4f8a356e88ed/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L101). Another possibility to look into could be a [`tf.init_scope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/init_scope) context, but make sure to fully read all the documentation about the caveats and behaviors.

TFF has a new communication primative called [`tff.federated_select`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_select) that might come in very helpful here. The intrinsic comes with two tutorials:

1. [Sending Different Data To Particular Clients With `tff.federated_select`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_select) which talks specifically about the communication primitive.
2. [Client-efficient large-model federated learning via `federated_select` and sparse aggregation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/sparse_federated_learning) which demonstrates using `federated_select` for federated learning for linear regression; and demonstrates the necessity of a "sparse aggregation" the difficulty you identified with padding out zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please give a look at the edit of the question? I did what you suggested but i can't understand what's wrong